# How to test new Firebase Crashlytics SDK?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I've implemented the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK replacing the old Fabric SDK. So, I need to test if this new changes reports something to Firebase Crashlytics Console, there is a web inside developer guide [test-implementation-new-sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation-new-sdk) but it is giving me a 404 error. So, I don't know how to test a crash to see if the sdk is reporting to the platform correctly.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried with:

```
throw new RuntimeException("FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS TEST::" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
```

and it worked for me.